# Django migrations change field type

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I've a FK to some model

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.FK(to=B)
```

I need to change it to IntegerField so it'll look like

```
class A(models.Model):
    b_id = models.IntegerField()
```

How can I add new migration without really changing anything in DB?

Answer (score 2):

Create a migration which will change the field type and then will rename the field:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '000X_the_name_of_prev_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='a',
            name='b',
            field=models.IntegerField(),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='a',
            old_name='b',
            new_name='b_id',
        ),
    ]
```

In fact at SQL level there will be two renames of the column `b_id -> b` and `b -> b_id` but the data in this column will be preserved.